# How many public static ips do one need if a PC is behind a wireless router?

Tags: router, ipv4, wireless, subnet, ip-address

If a PC is connected to internet through a wireless router. 
How many public static ips do one got to get from the ISP.
Do the router and PC both require one static IP.

What if I want to add more PC to internet using Public IP (so they are reachable from outside).  How to create the subnet of public IPS

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't require any IPv4 address at all. IPv6 only will work just fine. To access IPv4 resources you'll need a gateway doing e.g. NAT64 which needs an IPv4 address.

Comment: now have not got ipv6 need ... addressing this case with in ipv4 system might be my concern. The other suggestion seems fine except it breaks whenever I have to add further more devices on our subnet.

Answer (score 1):

You require *one* public IPv4 address to participate on the Internet, either static or dynamic. Behind the single IP address and a NAT router can be any number of (privately addressed) clients.

If you require more public addresses (e.g. to offer services to the Internet) you need to ask your ISP. Normally, you'd get a *routed subnet* with one gateway address used by the ISP router or service and the rest for your use.

Comment: zac, I have to host some services (pub accessible) on one or few PC's behind the router (wireless).  Should i ask the isp to get me a subnet with a.a.a.a/30 for 3 hosts plus a gateway or a.a.a.a/29 for 7 hosts plus gateway. (NAT does not expose the PC's to outer world though from with in the subnet the PC's can access net freely. )

Comment: think this is what you seems to point towards... fine.

Comment: @samshers /30 or /31 only give you *one* usable address. /29 has 6 usable addresses minus one for ISP gateway. 7 hosts require at least a /28 subnet with 13 user addresses (2^(32-28)-3). For serious service hosting you probably wouldn't use a wireless network for the DMZ.

Comment: how can /31 have one usable address (2(addresses) - 3(Net ID + B. Cast + GW) = -1), so seems no network or usable ip is possible.

Comment: @samshers /31 is a special case, see [RFC 3021](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3021). Sadly, it's not always supported.